# Create a uint64 from a 7-byte list

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, .net-4.8

I receive binary data from a hardware device, which includes bit-packed 7-byte messages. e.g. one data element `x` is taken from bits 6-9 across byte boundaries.

Since it's only 7 bytes I thought it might be convenient to create a `UInt64` which I can then fairly easy manipulate using binary operators:

```
//pseudo
void receiveData(IList<byte> bytes)
{
  UInt64 data = ???(bytes,0,7);
  var x = (bytes >> 6) & (0b1111);
  ...
}
```

How can I get `bytes` -> `data`? Clearly one option is using a loop but is there a .Net API to handle this already?

(other ways to do this are also welcome)

Comment: Be aware of the possible hardware vendor implémentation. I remember a project where we translated bytes from a Schneider device, and "mantisse" (dont know the english word) was inverted : -1 meant 1. That lead to a lot of headaches...

Comment: @Romka and I thought little/big endian was bad enough!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want [`BitConverter.ToInt64(byte[] value, int startIndex)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint64(v=vs.110)).

> The ToInt64 method converts the bytes from index startIndex to startIndex + 7 to a Int64 value. The order of bytes in the array must reflect the endianness of the computer system's architecture; for more information, see the Remarks section of the BitConverter class topic.

Comment: I've used that before, but can I put less than 8 bytes in and still read `int64`?

Comment: Add a padding zero byte?

Comment: @Mr.Boy: Use `ToUInt64` and just `&` out the extra bits afterwards.

Comment: The message is bit packed. Your answer shows you to extract an 8 Byte uint64 from a byte array by taking the first 8 bytes starting from byte index `startIndex`. This is not the question

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins once the OP has an uint64, the bit masking and shifting is easy.

Comment: @AKX I agree the bit0manipulation isn't part of my question, but expanding your answer with an example would make it much better, especially as there is an extra step.

Answer (score 1):

There are no built-in libraries to accomplish this task, nor 3rd party libraries, that I am aware of.

The build in method `BitConverter.ToInt64(byte[] value, int startIndex)` will throw an `System.ArgumentException: 'Destination array is not long enough.` If you pass just 7 bytes to it.

You could pad your 7 bytes with an an eight byte if you wish to work with the this method

```cs
static void receiveData(byte[] bytes)
{
    var padded = new byte[8];
    Array.Copy(bytes, padded, bytes.Length);
    var data = BitConverter.ToUInt64(padded, 0);
    var x = (data >> 6) & (0b1111);
    //...
}
```

If efficiency is your aim then unpacking the data manually in an unrolled loop is the way to go:

```cs
static void receiveData(byte[] bytes)
{
    var data = (ulong)bytes[0] + 
        ((ulong)bytes[1] << 8) +
        ((ulong)bytes[2] << 16) +
        ((ulong)bytes[3] << 24) +
        ((ulong)bytes[4] << 32) +
        ((ulong)bytes[5] << 40) +
        ((ulong)bytes[6] << 48);
    var x = (data >> 6) & (0b1111);
    //...
}
```

There are various less efficent on liners lines to accomplish both of the above tasks.

For the later, a one liner::

```cs
static void receiveData(byte[] bytes)
{
   var data = (ulong)Enumerable.Range(0, bytes.Length)
     .Sum(i=> ((long)bytes[i]) << (i * 8));
    var x = (data >> 6) & (0b1111);
    //...
}
```

As seen with various networking code in CSharp, you must extract raw bits at the binary level from each byte using a byte index, and then use a mask and shift operations, and often need to use addition operations when bit indexes for your data point cross word boundaries of your byte.

Since you are going to be doing such bit operations anyway another alterative is to build a class with fields such that properties access the bytes individually by index.

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    private byte[] data;
    public MyClass(byte[] bytes)
    {
        //TODO check bytes is not null and is correct length 
        bytes = data;
    }
    public int X => (data[0] >> 6) & (0b1111);
    public int Y => ((data[0] >> 6) & ~(0b1111)) + ((data[1] >> 2) & (0b11));
}
```

If your data is only 7 bytes, then you can first convert the data to a uint64 and then use binary operations to extract the bits you are looking for.

If you data is more than 8 bytes, as alternative, you can use a `System.Numerics.BigInteger`, which you can construct using a `Byte[]` and use binary operations

```cs
var big = new BigInteger(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,11});
var shifted = big>>65; // skip 8 bytes
var wanted= shifted & 7; // take first 3 bit-packed values
```

Another option is to use c/c++ which allows you to use union structs, again as seen with networking code, and pass it back to managed code.

As far as built-in options, your last resort is the `BitArray` which can give you a list or array of booleans from the an arbitrary number of bytes passed to the constructor, but this leaves you very lacking for any other manipulation of those booleans:

```cs
var b = new BitArray(bytes);
var j = b.Cast<Boolean>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

One option I considered is this, using the magic of LINQ:

```
UInt64 data = bytes.Take(7).Reverse().Aggregate(0ul, (result, next) => (result<<8) + next);
```

Old-school C coders will shudder at the likely inefficiency but I found it quite interesting. I had to add `Reverse()` because I am little-Endian, and I can't see any way to do `result + next << (8*index` in a lambda.